# Reconnect to running cell output in Azure ML Notebook after refreshing page

Tags: jupyter-notebook, azure-machine-learning-service

I am using Notebooks in Azure ML and i have the following issue. If I have a long running cell and my browser loses connection, or I refresh the page, the cell will still be running in the background and the output stops showing in the notebook.

Is there a way to force Azure Notebooks to reconnect to the output of that running cell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no direct way to force Azure Notebooks to reconnect to the output of a running cell once the connection is lost.
Alternate solution this can be to save the output in a file. So even if you loose the connection the cell will execute in background and save the output in a file.
To do this you can use the `%%capture` magic command to capture the output of a cell and save it to a file.

Here is an example:

```py
cap=None
```

```py
%%capture cap
import  time
def  long_running_function():
for  i  in  range(10):
    print(i)
    time.sleep(0.01)
if  __name__ == "__main__":
    long_running_function()
with  open('output.txt', 'w') as  f:
    f.write(cap.stdout)
```

With the above code snippet the output will store in file once the cell is executed successfully even if the connection to output is lost.

[image]